# No midp20.jar in J2ME SDK 8.3

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

I downloaded *[Oracle Java ME SDK 8.3 for Ubuntu Linux](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javame/javame-sdk/downloads/javamesdkdownloads-2166598.html)*.

To create Java midlets I need the midp api which was supposed to be in lib directory. Currently I am having just these files in lib directory 
[image]

Has Oracle stopped support for J2ME mobile devices ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't looked into it too much, but I'm fairly sure you just need SDK 3.4
The problem is that JavaME isn't just one thing. Most people think "cellphones" (MIDlets) when they hear JavaME, but it's actually a lot of other things too, like for example Blu-ray Disc Java (BD-J Xlets) or apps for office hardware like printers (also Xlets, but yet again a different API).

Seems to me that SDK 8> just focuses on Xlet development, while SDK <8 focuses on MIDlets. No point in making new SDK's for MIDlet development when there are no new MIDP API's.