# NetBeans won't detect java ME platform

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me

I am totally new at programming with Java and mobile App development. I have installed Netbeans v8.2 (the full bundle) then installed Java ME 8.3/8/3.4, but every time I go about adding any of the platforms it tells me that the detection's failed. I then tried to add Java ME manually but when I write in a new file it doesn't seem to recognize any of the standard built-in functions. Also, tried installing the Java Me plugins from the site, but it made no effect of adding any features to the IDE. How could I get the IDE to detect Java ME platform?

- I have JDK x64 v8u144 installed and Netbeans had no problems with detecting it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254494/no-midp20-jar-in-j2me-sdk-8-3

Comment: solved my problem by going to this directory from jdk installation folder jdk-dir>jre\lib\security\java.security and adding this setting:

`jdk.serialFilter=*

 
sun.rmi.registry.registryFilter=*

 
sun.rmi.transport.dgcFilter=\

 
java.rmi.server.ObjID;\

 
java.rmi.server.UID;\

 
java.rmi.dgc.VMID;\

 
java.rmi.dgc.Lease;\

 
maxdepth=5;maxarray=10000`

Comment: Check this [Java ME SDK not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501075/java-me-sdk-not-recognized-by-netbeans-eclipse/49603180#49603180)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing [JAVA ME SDK 3.4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/sdk/default-303768.html)? It contains plugins for netbeans and the SDK of the same instead of installing of  the  Java ME 8.

Comment: yes, I did.  I get the same error for all Java ME versions.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error.. Installing Sun Java Wireless Toolkit worked for me.

Link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137162.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with JDK version. The issue was resolved by downgrading from jdk-8u241 to jdk-8u112. I'm using Netbeans 7.4 and Java ME SDK 3.4.